# Partial Derivatives: $f(x,y) = x^5y^4+\sin\left({x\over{y}}\right)$

Tags: calculus

Given the function:$$ f(x,y) = x^5y^4+\sin\left({x\over{y}}\right)$$
How can I find such partial derivatives as $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$, $f_{yx}$, and $f_{yy}$?

Comment: You meant partial _derivatives_ right?

Comment: Assuming, as EuYu suggests, that you mean partial derivatives, you find them the same way you always find partial derivatives --- by differentiating with respect to one variable, while treating the other as a constant. Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Yes, derivatives. I fixed it now.

Comment: Think about what $f_{xx}$ means.  Let $F := f_x$.  Then $f_{xx} = F_x$.  Just take the partial derivative of the partial derivative.

Comment: I'm getting stuck in what exactly the notation is asking me to do. But if all it's asking is to basically take it twice then I think I got it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have $f(x,y) = x^5y^4+\sin\left({x\over{y}}\right)$:

- For $f_{xx}$ its asking you to take the derivative -- of the function -- twice of $x$ and treat $y$ as a constant. Same logic with $f_{yy}$
- For $f_{xy}$ its asking you to take the derivative -- of the function -- of $x$ treat $y$ as a constant, then take the derivative of $y$ and treat $x$ as a constant. Same logic $f_{yx}$